# Visual Studio 2012 Crashes when using CTRL F

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio has recently started crashing any time I use `CTRL F` to try to search the document.  The only update I have recently installed is one to the NuGet Package manager.  I have changed no other settings recently.

I tried to retrieve the logs, but everytime I update them by typing `devenv /log` into `Run`, it launches Visual Studio, and the error log (found in `AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0`) is full of reports about starting up visual studio and includes no warnings or errors.

Not sure what to do, `CTRL F` is kind of important for coding, for me at least... and I think everyone.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try installing [VS 2012 Update 3](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2835600).  You can also use inline search as a work around (CTRL+I).

Comment: @JohnnyHK thats a useful trick, already installed that update though, thanks.

Comment: Alternatively you could try cd'ing into the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE and running Devenv.exe /ResetSettings... May or may not help!

Answer (score 0):

Ever thought about reinstalling or using the repair function? If that does not help take a look at the event viewer of windows. Maybe it contains some other outputs.

Comment: good idea, thanks, I don't have a moment to give it a shot now, but I will be sure to upvote/accept as soon as I can try it out.